# Update recyclerview item from background thread after changing configuration

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment`. Also I have an `AsyncTask` which updates items of `RecyclerView` from background thread. The problem is when I rotate the device (or cause any other configuration change),  the `AsyncTask` cannot update views.

Here you can see the simplified code:

`HomeFragment`:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
        return new HomeFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        Activity activity = requireActivity();
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Item1", "Item2", "Item3"));
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(activity, items);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
    }
}
```

The adapter of RecyclerView and its inner `AsyncTask` class:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<String> items;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(mItemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ListAdapter mAdapter;
        final TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, ListAdapter mAdapter) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
            this.name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Task task = new Task();
                task.execute();
            });
        }
    }

    class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            mRecyclerView.post(() ->
                    ((ViewHolder) Objects.requireNonNull(mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(0))).
                            name.setText(String.valueOf(values[0])));
            mRecyclerView.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
                publishProgress(i);
                SystemClock.sleep(500);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            ((ViewHolder) Objects.requireNonNull(mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(0))).name.setText("task is finished");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I used `mRecyclerView.post()` method to avoid touching views from non UI thread. How I can update items after rotating the device?

What I tried before:

- changing data set of adapter and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`
- creating a method in Fragment for updating items and calling it from `AsyncTask`
- resetting adapter for RecyclerView
- ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is deprecated since API level 30. It has issues especially for configuration changes [per documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

> AsyncTask was intended to enable proper and easy use of the UI thread.
> However, the most common use case was for integrating into UI, and
> that would cause Context leaks, missed callbacks, or crashes on
> configuration changes.

And because of these issues it shouldn't be used in long running tasks.

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
> at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of
> time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by
> the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor
> and FutureTask.

### **Issue:**

When you run tasks in `doInBackground`, when the configuration changes, the activity is recreated (i.e. the old activity is destroyed, and a new activity is created); but the `AsyncTask` that was attached to the old activity continues to run (causing memory leaks); and so later on when `onPostExecute()` is ready to publish the results to the UI thread; it will release them to the destroyed activity rather than the current activity displayed on the screen; and the user won't see them consequently. Therefore the result is dismissed in your case.

So, it's recommended to see other background threading alternatives such as `Executors` either with callbacks to update the UI or with `ViewModel` (which survive configuration changes) & `LiveData` to publish the results to the the UI.

### Solution With Executor

- Here `Executor` is provided:

Listener:

```
interface ProgressListener {
    void onPostExecute();

    void onProgressUpdate(int value);
}
```

Fragment:

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(activity, items, new ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute() {
                ((ListAdapter.ViewHolder) Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.
                        findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(0))).name.setText("task is finished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressUpdate(int value) {
                recyclerView.post(() ->
                        ((ListAdapter.ViewHolder) Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(0))).
                                name.setText(String.valueOf(value)));
                recyclerView.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter: just use single thread executor:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ProgressListener progressListener;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items, ProgressListener listener) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
        progressListener = listener;
    }
    
    
    // ........... CODE IS OMITTED
    
    
    // ViewHolder constructor
    
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, ListAdapter mAdapter) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
            this.name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
                        progressListener.onProgressUpdate(i);
                        SystemClock.sleep(500);
                    }
                    progressListener.onPostExecute();
                });
            });
        }
    

}
```

### With AsyncTask

- If you still need to solve this using AsyncTask, which is not recommended as previously mentioned. You need someway to preserve the adapter & AsnyncTask instances; here a ViewModel is used:

Create the ViewModel to save the adapter & AsnyncTask instances

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> myTask;
    ListAdapter adapter;

    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

}
```

In fragment: Instantiate the adapter only if it's null, and pass an instance of AsynkTask to the adapter:

```
    if (viewModel.adapter == null)
        viewModel.adapter = new ListAdapter(activity, items, viewModel);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(viewModel.adapter);
```

Finally use the `ViewModel AsynkTask` instance in the adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // ......... code is omitted

    private AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> task;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items, AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> myTask) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
        this.task = myTask;
    }
    
    // ......... code is omitted
    
    
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ListAdapter mAdapter;
        final TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, ListAdapter mAdapter) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
            this.name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                task = new Task();
                task.execute();
            });
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for update recycler view in screen rotation.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(adapter!=null){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Call `setRetainInstance(true)` in either of `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` or `onActivityCreated()` methods.

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Async task by default work on background thread, we cannot update our ui from background thread it's used for intensive works such as network calls etc. Please try running a

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // WORK on UI thread here
        }
    });
```

statement in your async task's onPostExecute method because it indicates your background processing is completed. put code that update views inside this run() method